# How to set up prettify so it doesn't remove multi-lines in parentheses?

Tags: typescript, prettier

This is how I want my code to look:

```
export type PasswordResetRequestServiceType = (
  WithFindAll<PasswordResetRequestResource, Params> &
  Service<PasswordResetRequestResource>
);
```

Here's what what prettify does:

```
export type PasswordResetRequestServiceType = WithFindAll<PasswordResetRequestResource, Params> &
  Service<PasswordResetRequestResource>;
```

Is there a way to configure prettify so that the prettify doesn't do that?

Thank you!